# Nifi processor to route flows based on changeable list of regex

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use Nifi to act as a router for syslog based on a list of regexes matching the syslog.body (nb as this is just a proof of concept I can change any part if needed)

The thought process is that via a separate system (for now, vi and a text file ) an admin can define a list of criteria (regex format for each seems sensible) which, if matched, would result in syslog messages being sent to a specific separate system (for example, all critical audit data (matched by the regex list) is sent to the audit system and all other data goes to the standard log store

I know that this can be done on Route by content processors but the properties are configured before the processor starts and an admin would have to stop the processor every time they need to make an edit

I would like to load the list of regex in periodically (automatically) and have the processor properties be updated

I don’t mind if this is done all natively in Nifi (but that is preferable for elegance and to save an external app being written) or via a REST API call driven by a python script or something (or can Nifi send REST calls to itself?!)

I appreciate a processor property cannot be updated while running, so it would have to be stopped to be updated, but that’s fine as the queue will buffer for the brief period.  Maybe a check to see if the file has changed could avoid outages for no reason rather than periodic update regardless, I can solve that problem later.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to use [`ScanContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ScanContent/index.html), a processor which specifies a dictionary file on disk which contains a list of search terms and monitors the file for changes, reloading in that event. The processor then applies the search terms to the content of incoming flowfiles and allows you to route them based on matches. While this processor doesn't support regular expressions as dictionary terms, you could make a slight modification to the code or use this as a baseline for a custom processor with those changes.

If that doesn't work for you, there are a number of [`LookupService`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/index.html) implementations which show how CSV, XML, property files, etc. can be monitored and read by the controller framework to provide an updated mapping of key/value pairs. These can also serve as a foundation for building a more complicated scan/match flow using the loaded terms/patterns.

Finally, if you have to rely on direct processor property updating, you can script this with the NiFi API calls to stop, update, and restart the processors so it can be done in near-real-time. To determine these APIs, visit the [API documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) or execute the desired tasks via the UI in your browser and use the Developer Tools to capture the HTTP requests being made.

Comment: Altering ScanContent is a really good shout actually , thanks, I’ll look into that.

Comment: If you're comfortable doing that, contributing that feature back via PR would definitely be helpful for the community. Thanks.

Comment: Let’s see how successful I am first!  but yes if it works I will